# Find, move, and create empty file in place of file that was moved

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking to make a crontab that will search through a directory and all subdirectories and find all files with extension *.mkv then move them to a different directory and create an empty file with the same name and extension in place of the original file.

So it would look like this:

> 1. find *.mkv in subdirectories of /home/user/directoryA/~
> 2. move *.mkv to /home/user/directoryB/
> 3. create empty *.mkv with same filename as the original in place of file in /home/user/directoryA/~

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process isn't too difficult if you recognize that when forming your new directory names, your old base directory will simply be a *substring* within the new directory name. Bash provides a *parameter expansion with substring replacement* that is tailor made for this process.

Essentially, you `find` each file below your source directory with the `*.mkv` extension, you use *parameter expansion with substring replacement* to form the new full-filename containing your destination directory, (e.g. `nffn="${ffn/$srcdir/$destdir}"`, where `ffn` is short for `full-filename` and `nffn` short for `new full-filename`)

With your new full-filename formed containing the updated path, it is just a matter of making sure the destination directory exists before moving the file. `mkdir -p` is perfect here as it will create the full path, and will not complain if the directory already exists. You simply use a *parameter expansin with substring removal* to isolate the new directory from the new full-filename to pass to `mkdir -p`, and finally, you check that `mkdir -p` succeeds or you handle the error, e.g.

```
## create new directory, handle error if create fails
mkdir -p "${nffn%/*}" || { 
    echo "error: creating '${nffn%/*}'" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Putting all the pieces together, you can do what you are attempting with a short script similar to the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

## source and destination directories, file pattern
#  (note: to change destdir, two arguments required
#         to change patrn, three arguments required)
srcdir="${1:-/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/debug/AAA}"
destdir="${2:-/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/debug/BBB}"
patrn="${3:-*.mkv}"

while read -r ffn; do               ## loop over each full-filename
    nffn="${ffn/$srcdir/$destdir}"  ## form new full-filename
    ## create new directory, handle error if create fails
    mkdir -p "${nffn%/*}" || { 
        echo "error: creating '${nffn%/*}'" >&2
        exit 1
    }
    mv "$ffn" "$nffn"               ## move full-filename to new full-filename
    touch "$ffn"                    ## touch full-filename for zero original
done < <(find "$srcdir" -name "$patrn")
```

(**note:** you can pass the directories and file pattern as positional parameters, but note, if you pass more than 1, you must pass each required parameter (or you could implement getotp))

**Initial Directories AAA & BBB**

```
$ tree AAA
AAA
├── a.mkv
├── b.mkv
├── dir1
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
├── dir2
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
├── dir3
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
└── dira
    ├── a.mkv
    └── b.mkv

$ tree BBB
BBB [error opening dir]
```

**Final Directories AAA & BBB**

```
$ bash mvemptydir.sh

$ tree AAA
AAA
├── a.mkv
├── b.mkv
├── dir1
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
├── dir2
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
├── dir3
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
└── dira
    ├── a.mkv
    └── b.mkv

$ tree BBB
BBB
├── a.mkv
├── b.mkv
├── dir1
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
├── dir2
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
├── dir3
│   ├── a.mkv
│   └── b.mkv
└── dira
    ├── a.mkv
    └── b.mkv
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

you can write a script like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /[ADDRESS]
find . -name *.mkv > /tmp/find_result.txt
mv `cut -f1 /tmp/find_result.txt` /backup/
touch `cut -f1 /tmp/find_result.txt`
```

1- go to your directory that you want to find this files

2- find all .mkv files and send the result to a file like /tmp/find_result.txt in this example

3- move all files (that save in file "/tmp/find_result.txt") to your desired directory (like "/backup" in this example)

4- finaly create empty file with same name (that save in file "/tmp/find_result.txt")

you can add this script to crontab.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a loop to do this for each file matching your criteria!

```
for f in `find . -name *.mkv`; do
    mv $f /home/user/directoryB/
    touch $f
done;
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could put this into a script and accept directoryA/B as arguments:

```
for f in `find $1 -name *.mkv`; do mv $f $2; touch $f; done;
```

and run as `./script.sh /home/user/directoryA/~ /home/user/directoryB/`